# Using VBA to assign a criterion for average.ifs()

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, average

I use the following formula in excel

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B4:B440;A4:A440;"<"&A441;A4:A440;">"&EDATE(A441;-6))
```

to get the average of a range of values, based on the values in an adjacent column. However I need to apply this formula for more than a thousand dates (column A contains dates). I have a macro, which asks the user to specify sheet name and date (using dialog boxes). So I would like to add some code, that takes the date specified by the user and replaces cell A441 from the above formula with it. Then copy the average, so that I can paste it where desired. Here is what I tried coding so far, with no success:

```
Sub Find()

Dim FindString As Date
Dim Sumact As Range
Dim Analyst As Double
Dim shname As String
        Do Until WorksheetExists(shname)
                      shname = InputBox("Enter sheet name")
                      If Not WorksheetExists(shname) Then MsgBox shname & " doesn't exist!", vbExclamation
                Loop
                Sheets(shname).Select
FindString = InputBox("Enter a Search value")
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With Sheets(shname).Range("A:A")
        Set Sumact = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Sumact Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Sumact, True
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
End If   
 Set Analyst = Application.AverageIf(Range(("B:B"), ("A:A")), "<Sumact")
Selection.Copy 
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't referencing the the call in column A sufficient? Why hardcode the date into the formula?

Answer (score 0):

You do not `Set` a variable unless you are setting an object like the cell returned by the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx). Assigning a double to a var should be simply equal (e.g. `=`).

```
Sub Make_AVERAGEIFS()

    Dim FindString As Date
    Dim Sumact As Range
    Dim Analyst As Double
    Dim shname As String
    Dim d As Integer, m As Integer, y As Integer

    Do Until WorksheetExists(shname)
                  shname = InputBox("Enter sheet name")
                  If Not WorksheetExists(shname) Then MsgBox shname & " doesn't exist!", vbExclamation
    Loop

    With worksSheets(shname)
        .Activate
        FindString = InputBox("Enter a Search value")
        If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
            With .Range("A:A")
                Set Sumact = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Sumact Is Nothing Then
                    Application.Goto Sumact, True
                Else
                    MsgBox "Nothing found"
                End If
            End With
        End If

        If IsDate(Sumact) Then
            d = Day(Sumact): m = Month(Sumact): y = Year(Sumact)
            Analyst = Application.AverageIfs(.Columns(2), _
                                             .Columns(1), "<" & DateSerial(y, m, d), _
                                             .Columns(1), ">" & DateSerial(y, m - 6, d))
        End If
    End With


    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

I suppose that searching for the date in column A is one way to check that the user has input a valid date but there must be other, less complicated methods. The [IsDate Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278584.aspx) that I have used above is one.